# How to skipt the prompt for time-triggered automation Shortcuts in iOS13?

Tags: ios, shortcut, automation, beta

I have created a simple shortcut that collects certain data and displays it via a push notification. I just told the app to run my shortcut every day at 10AM.

The feature certainly works, however there’s this annoying thing when the first thing I get is a notification asking me if I want the shortcut to be run. It runs only after I confirm it. This is very annoying since it defeats the purpose of automation which implies that the shortcut should be run automatically without any input from me.

For people here that are familiar with the matter, is there a way to bypass this annoyance?

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround that I have gotten to work in my testing, but if you use automatic do not disturb you might have to set it to only run at the specific time that DND is enabled automatically.

Basically set auto DND and then make an automation for when DND is turned on. In order to ensure that it won't run whenever I use DND, I created a few shortcuts.

[MatchTime](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/242f4a2d293f4eaf8dff01c773588469)
and [DND Auto](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/1a5a77b3f423482aa52e0fed44737e5d)

Just set a DND enabled automation to run the "DND Auto" shortcut

Comment: Just realized that someone else already figured this out [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/d8wrjc/real_automation_shortcut_working_alone_ios_131/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)